# Google Analytics API: Create a new profile

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to create a new profile via the Google Analytics API?

This way we can automatically register the tracking when we have new landingpages created.
I am curious if anyone is working with an automated way of automatically setting up GA tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! The Google Analytics Management API has changed... As you can see from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#methods), available methods for profiles are `delete`, `get`, `insert`, `list`, `patch` and `update`.

You can even insert new [Web Properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties), but beware of the 20 properties per account limit.

Answer (score 0):

No - the Google Analytics Management API is read-only. As you can see from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#methods), the only available method for accounts, properties, and profiles is `list`.